# WordPress Pages - No Pages Found

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that contains about 18 different pages. While logged in as administrator, I click on Pages.

I see the following

```
All (20) | Mine (19) | Published (19) | Draft (1)
No Pages Found
```

I've repaired the database. I've disabled all plugins. I can create new pages, which increases the totals, but still displays No Pages Found.

I can edit the page via the front end. I can click on the WordPress bar Edit Page which takes me to the back-end and I'm allowed to edit the page and save it. When I click back to All Pages... No Pages Found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you disable all plugin then check

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to default Wordpress theme and switching back to your theme to rule out any theme-specific problem. I have had same problem and this helped for me.